# Rspec gets strip test will not run

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to spec the current method:

```
class CLIinterface
  def units_inputs  
    puts "\n\n________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\nEnter the desired unit class of measurement desired for current temperature:\n\t- Typing 'standard', 'default' or 'any word != imperial or metric' induces the selection of Standard (Kelvin)\n\t- Typing 'imperial' induces the selection of Imperial (Fahrenheit)\n\t- Typing 'metric' induces the selection of Metric (Celsius)\n________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n"

    # \n
    # \n________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    # \nEnter the desired unit class of measurement desired for current temperature:
    # \n\t- Typing 'standard', 'default' or 'any word != imperial or metric' induces the selection of Standard (Kelvin)
    # \n\t- Typing 'imperial' induces the selection of Imperial (Fahrenheit)
    # \n\t- Typing 'metric' induces the selection of Metric (Celsius)
    # \n________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    # \n      

    @units_input = gets.strip.to_s.downcase
  end
end
```

How do I go about testing that the instance variable `@units_input` is set to the users input through `gets.strip.to_s.downcase`? I am running into trouble with it. I cannot find an answer.

```
 describe 'units_inputs' do
   let(:units_input) { double("metric") }
   let(:unit) { CLIinterface.new}

   it "once" do
   # have and_return return the stub, not the symbol
   expect(unit).to receive(:gets).and_return(units_input).once

   # call the method
   unit.units_inputs

   # check that the instance variable is set
   expect(unit.instance_method_get(:@units_input)).to eq(units_input)
 end
```

I've tried pseudo-following the relish site, but the above throws:

```
  Failures:

  1) units_inputs once
  Failure/Error: unit.units_inputs
   # <Double "metric"> received unexpected message :strip with (no args)
   # ./cli.rb:14:in `units_inputs'
   # ./spec/cli_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, it did not save all of the text I typed in prior. I re-added the statement/question I have. Thank you for pointing out my flaw.

Comment: Are finding a way to mimic user's input in Rspec?

Comment: Could you provide an example by chance? Like I said I have tried and read many things, so idk what I have done/tried that you may be suggesting.

Comment: I guess yes, thats what I am trying to find.

Comment: I have `undefined local variable or method 'current_temp' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UnitsInputs...`

Comment: ? Im not sure how this is possible when current_temp doesnt show up in the code whatsoever?

Comment: I copied your code, it was in the previous version. Now I have `spec/cli_spec.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need doubles here. It's perfectly fine to operate on primitives sometimes (especially since you'd need the double to conform to multiple string methods).

I'd write your spec like this:

```
describe 'units_inputs' do
  let(:units_input) { 'Imperial   ' } # mixed case, some spaces
  let(:unit) { CLIinterface.new }

  it "once" do
    expect(unit).to receive(:gets).and_return(units_input).once
    unit.units_inputs
    expect(unit.instance_variable_get(:@units_input)).to eq('imperial') # downcased, spaces stripped
  end
end
```

On a second thought, you don't even need `instance_variable_get` here, as the current code returns `@units_input` as its implicit return value. Further simplification is available:

```
describe 'units_inputs' do
  let(:units_input) { 'Imperial   ' } # mixed case, some spaces
  let(:unit) { CLIinterface.new }

  it "once" do
    expect(unit).to receive(:gets).and_return(units_input).once
    result = unit.units_inputs
    expect(result).to eq('imperial') # downcased, spaces stripped
  end
end
```

You can even inline `unit.units_input` and it'd work, but it looks a bit weird. The code is all expectations and no obvious "meat".

```
expect(unit).to receive(:gets).and_return(units_input).once
expect(unit.units_inputs).to eq('imperial') # downcased, spaces stripped
```

Comment: I would kiss you if you were here.... Thank you so much! very useful and thank you for the simplifications/abstractions throughout till the final condensed version.

Answer (score -1):

Modify your spec like this:

```
describe 'units_inputs' do
  let(:units_input) { double("metric") }
  let(:unit) { CLIinterface.new}
  it "once"
    # have and_return return the stub, not the symbol
    expect(unit).to receive(:gets).and_return(units_input).once

    # call the method
    unit.units_inputs

    # check that the instance variable is set
    expect(unit.instance_method_get(:@units_input)).to eq(units_input)
  end
end
```

Comment: `Failures:

  1) units_inputs once
     Failure/Error: unit.units_inputs
       #<Double "metric"> received unexpected message :strip with (no args)
     # ./cli.rb:14:in 'units_inputs'
     # ./spec/cli_spec.rb:11:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>`